# Can not unmount ssh connection after hibernation or momentary connection loss

Tags: sshfs, unmounting

I work on a mounted directory to a cluster through sshfs. However, sometimes my connection fails for a second and the mounting stops working. The problem is that I can not umount to be able to restart the connection.

The temporal solution I am using is reseting the whole computer, which is pretty unconvenient.
I found a solution in *Superuser* but the answers are not completely explained and I am not sure on how to apply the [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/365579/cant-access-folders-mounted-by-sshfs-after-sleep-or-when-connection-lost) and I can not ask for clarification as I lack reputation points.

I'd appreciate a well commented solution for an unexperienced user. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: In the comments @Jaromanda X suggested doing `killall -9 sshfs`. This stops all the mountings but they are still displayed in the Files explorer and I can not mount again.

Comment: which of those 3 commands doesn't work for you?

Comment: The problem is umount, it doesn't work so I can not restart the mounting

Comment: oh, so even after you `killall -9 sshfs` you can't umount?

Comment: no, I didn't dare to try ``killall -9`` because I couldn't find what is the -9 doing

Comment: oh, that just kills all `sshfs` processes - nothing sinister - `-9` is the signal to send (it's actually 9 ... but never mind that)

Comment: It is not working. I edited the question.

Comment: I didn't suggest you SHOULD do that, `-9` is a LAST resort, but as a test, it's interesting